# How do I set up file sharing between Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, file-sharing

I recently set up an old machine with Edubuntu 9.x (because if its nice set of educational games for my daughter).

I would like to set up file sharing on my home network, which is comprised mostly of Windows boxes XP-and-up. Being a noob with Ubuntu, I don't know where to start.

How do I get started with sharing files between the different computers on my home network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAMBA is probably the best place to start. To quote [their own site](http://www.samba.org/) -

> Samba is the standard Windows
>   interoperability suite of programs for
>   Linux and Unix.
>
> Samba is software that can be run on a platform other than Microsoft Windows, for example, UNIX, Linux, IBM System 390, OpenVMS, and other operating systems. Samba uses the TCP/IP protocol that is installed on the host server. When correctly configured, **it allows that host to interact with a Microsoft Windows client or server as if it is a Windows file and print server.**

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/samba.htm)

Comment: I think I can do that. Thanks for the link to the tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

With Ubuntu is very easy: Using Nautilus (the File Explorer like applicaction) Right click on the folder you want to share, search for the Share options command, click on it, Edubuntu/Ubuntu will ask you to automatically install the Windows folder sharing libraries.

Then you can adjust the parameters in System/Preferences File Sharing Options.

The command names can vary, because my PC runs in Spanish and I can't see how are named in English